How to include class defined in a cpp file
I defined a PoseCtrl class in pose_ctrl.cpp and pose_ctrl.h, then put them into path： package/include.
Then I wrote a node in robort_position_ctrl.cpp and robort_position_ctrl.h, and include pose_ctrl.h in robort_position_ctrl.h：
#include "pose_ctrl.h"

my workspace is like:
/catkin_ros
  /robort_position_ctrl
    /include
      pose_ctrl.h
      pose_ctrl.cpp
    /src
      robort_position_ctrl.h
      robort_position_ctrl.cpp

I put "include"folder into cmakelist file：
 include_directories(
          include
          ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
          ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS}
      ) 

But when I run :
catkin build

I meet build errors:
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/robort_position_ctrl.dir/src/robort_position_ctrl.cpp.o: in function `main':
robort_position_ctrl.cpp:(.text+0x358): undefined reference to `RelativePoseCtrl::RelativePoseCtrl()'


Its a linker error. In plain text, none of the object files you are linking your executable (main) against contains a definition of the constructor of RelativePoseCtrl. For more you need to provide more information about the contents of your object and header files. Also it would be necessary to know what you are building, exectuable (I assume), library, in your cmakelists.
